# How to check if a string in one field exist in every element of a comma separated field

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table which contains two fields. The first is `name` of type `string`. The second contains one or more strings separated by comma (but it can contain a single string with no commas at all)

I want to construct a query to know if the string in the `name` field **does not** exist in **every** comma separated strings in the `names` field.

Example 1:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
name          names
---------------------------------------------------------
myname        xmyname,myname,mynamey
```

All the comma separated strings contain the word `myname`. So the query shoudl not return this row.

But, Example 2:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
name          names
---------------------------------------------------------
myname        x,myname,mynamey
```

Should be returned. Because x does not contain myname.

The condition is that, if the string in the field `name` does not exists in **each** of the comma separated strings in the `names` field, then return the row.

This is not correct as this query will not return true in example 2 (which contains `x` which does not contain `myname`).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

1) There is not limit of how many commas there. It can be 0 commas or more. How to deal with this?

2) The strings are variables. It is not always the case that the string is `myname`. Each row contains a different string in the `name` field.

Comment: You really need to rethink your database. Moves those "names" to a seperate table. If you're gonna do this kind of stuff, you should not go with a single column to manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
where not concat(names, ',') regexp replace('^([^,]*{n}[^,]*,)*$', '{n}', name)
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jhhkiQVNFuenN1EiFkJn5t/0)

How to read the pattern:

The inner pattern `[^,]*{n}[^,]*,` means

- Any non comma character `[^,]` repeated any number of times (`*` means no times or multiple times).
- followed by the value of the column `name` (`{n}` is a placeholder and will be replaced with the actual value using the `replace()` function)
- followed by any non comma character `[^,]` repeated any number of times
- followed by a comma

The outer pattern `^({inner_pattern})*$` means

- Start of the string (`^`)
- followed by the inner pattern repeated any number of times
- followed by end of string (`$`)

To make this work, a comma is appended to the `names` column (`concat(names, ',')`), so that every element in the string ends with a comma.

The pattern will ensure, that any element in the comma separated string contains the value of the `name` column. Since you want the opposite result, we use `where not ..`.

Comment: This seems working. Can you plz provide explanation of the query so I can understand and accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry just one more question. Everything is clear, but how does the command loop over (goes through every element in the comma separated string). The example works but I do not get how? For example, the SQL command `concat(names, ',') regexp replace('^([^,]*{n}[^,]*,)*$', '{n}', name)` with this string `x,myname,mynamey` in the `names` column, and `myname' in the `name` column, to me, the regexp is matched in the middle string `myname` so the regexp will return `true`? But in my case, I want it to return false because `x` does not contain `myname`.

Comment: `x,` doesn't match the inner pattern, because it doesn't contain `myname`. But the outer pattern only "allows" repeats of the inner pattern between start `^` and end `$` of the string. Consider a simplified example where we want only allow digits in the string. The *inner pattern* would be `[0-9]`. The *outer pattern* would be `^[0-9]*$`. `x123` wouldn't match the whole pattern, though `1`, `2` and `3` do match the inner pattern. That are `^` and `$` which make the pattern strict. If you remove them, then `x123` would match.

Comment: @user9371654 Go to https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui and paste `Grammar  ::= ( [^,]* 'myname' [^,]* ',' )*` in to "Edit Grammar" tab. Then click on "View Diagram" and try to construct `x,myname,mynamey` with those rules.

Answer (score 0):

This answer started off giving an incorrect `REGEXP` solution.  But the best thing to do here would be to fix your data model, such that each name in the `names` column is actually on a separate row:

```
name     | names
myname   | xmyname
myname   | myname
myname   | mynamey
somename | x
somename | myname
somename | mynamey
```

Now we can do a simple aggregation query to answer your question:

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN names NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%') THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

### Demo

Comment: @ As I said earlier: This will not work. '%myname%' is not a fixed string. It is just an example of a string that can be inside the `name` field. How to replace `%myname%` with the result of `select name`

Comment: Thanks. And I can not change the DB BTW. So this query will work without making the fix you mentioned. I understand this is not ideal format to separate strings with comma inside a text field. But this is how it is now and I can not change it.

Comment: You would need some seriously powerful regex support to do what you want to do, and from what I read even MySQL 8+ might fall short.  I vote for biting the bullet now and changing your design.

Comment: I still do not think your query will capture the case when the `name` appear only in one but not all of the comma separated strings. May be instead of `> 0` I should use `= the number of comma separated strings`?

Comment: No, you misread my answer.  We are aggregating by `name`, and keeping a count of each time that the `names` value does _not_ contain that `name`.  So, asserting that the count be greater than zero matches your criteria.  I have added a demo link to my answer.

Comment: My answer is working in the demo.  You have some other table collation problem, from the looks of the error message.  I have never seen that error before.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "myname" does not appear *twice* between two commas, you can count the commas and "myname"s:

```
where (length(names) - length(replace(names, ','))) >=
       length(names) - length(replace(names, 'myname', '12345'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve it. 1) `myname` is not a fixed string. It is an example of a variable string that can appear in the `name` field. 2) Plz note there are two fields: `name` and `names`. I need to check the the string in the field `name` appear in each string in the comma separated strings in the `names` filed. 3) The `names` field does not end with comma. 4) the `names` field can contain 0 commas (if it contains a single string), but still even in this case the string in the field `name` should appear in the single string in the `names` field.

Comment: @user9371654 Please _don't_ store CSV in your tables this way.  This will result in your having to use some bufugly SQL to get your queries done.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  Thanks. I know. This is the situation now.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this using the following `SQL` query

```
SELECT 
name, names
FROM 
`tablename` 
WHERE 
(LENGTH(names) - LENGTH(REPLACE(names, ',', '')) + 1) 
=  
ROUND (   
  (
        LENGTH(names)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( names, name, "") ) 
  )/ LENGTH(name)       
);
```

**Explanation:-**

This Will give you how many words are separated with `,`

```
(LENGTH(names) - LENGTH(REPLACE(names, ',', '')) + 1) -
```

Following is matching the `name` in each row and returning how many times it found

```
 ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(names)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( names, name, "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH(name)        
)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/069e4b/15)